# Fourier transform of [something]*Gaussian

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, integral-transforms, deconvolution

It has been 20 years since failed to understand Fourier transforms during my formal education. I am trying to solve an optical problem, and it looks as though the Fourier transform should be helpful. I have been reading up, but I don't understand the transforms well enough to work through a simpler example. And in the end I really need to figure out how to deal with a more complicated one.
A less complicated one, that I could feed through a solver program so that I know which answer I'm trying to reproduce is:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \frac 1{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac 12 \frac {(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}dx=\mu^2+\sigma^2 $$
Which is a Gaussian distribution multiplied with $x^2$; $\sigma$ and $\mu$ have their usual meanings of standard deviation and mean. I have more complicated versions where I have all sorts of sin or cos terms instead of the $x^2$. But I'm focusing on this less complicated one, since I expect understanding this one will help me work my way up to the others. Taking the constant terms out from the integral is obvious:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \frac 1{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac 12 \frac {(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}dx=\frac 1{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-\frac 12 \frac {(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}dx$$
And I notice it vaguely resembles the formula for convolution where $f(x)=x^2$ and g is of the form $g(x-\mu)=e^{-ax^2}$. But I fail to understand the notation of the convolution theorem, and am inexperienced in the required maths (I do get the intuition: in the transform-domain we can add/subtract/use-algebra-to-simplify the transformed results and then leverage those results to solve our initial problem).

In the tutorials I found online, the $e^{-i\omega t}$ magically appears at this point; I guess if I can see behind this magic I am a big step forward.

So, to be specific about the questions:

1. Am I right to suspect that we can relatively easily solve this using a Fourier transform?
2. In the notation of convolution: what is f*g(x) as opposed to f(x)*g(x)? Am I right to understand that it is the same as f(g(x)), which is a very common notation to describe the chain rule for derivatives, which I know as (f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))*g'(x)?
3. How do I move forward? In other words, can I use the convolution theorem to move forward, and how do I apply it?

thanks for your time and help.

UPDATE:
All right, I have thought about it a little more. And I found a source that helps: $\hat F(0)=\int F(t)e^{-i*0*t}dt =\int F(t)dt$. Anyone who ever writes a tutorial on this aimed to inspire people to start using FT, without understanding the full proofs: you may want to lead with that. :)

doing this, I arrive at the correct answer! Could anyone confirm if I applied the time shifting and the derivative rules correctly?

I let $$F(t)=\frac {1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac 1 2 \frac {t^2}{\sigma^2}} $$
And found in a table $$\mathcal{F}(F(t))=\hat F(\omega) = e^{-\frac 1 2 \sigma^2 \omega^2}$$
Time shift rule: $\mathcal{F}(f(t-t_0))=e^{-i\omega t_0} \hat{f}(\omega) $ so that:$$\mathcal{F}(F(t-\mu))=e^{-i\omega\mu} \hat{F}(\omega)=e^{-i\omega\mu-\frac 1 2 \sigma^2 \omega^2} $$
Derivative rule: $\mathcal{F}(t^2 f(t))= i^2 \frac{d^2}{d\omega^2}\hat{f}(\omega)=-\frac{d^2}{d\omega^2}\hat{f}(\omega)$, then I think that:
$$\mathcal{F}(t^2 F(t-\mu))= \frac {d^2}{d\omega^2} e^{-i\omega\mu}\hat{F}(\omega)=\frac {d^2}{d\omega^2}e^{-i\omega\mu-\frac 1 2 \sigma^2 \omega^2}=(\mu^2+\sigma^2-2i\sigma^2\omega\mu-\sigma^4\omega^2)e^{-i\omega\mu-\frac 1 2 \sigma^2 \omega^2}$$
So that if I fill in $\omega = 0$, I arrive at the correct answer!

My specific remaining question: $\mathcal{F}(t^2 F(t-\mu))$, shouldn't that have been $\mathcal{F}((t-\mu)^2 F(t-\mu))$? (in other words, did I arrive at the correct answer despite making an error?)

Is it maybe also true that $\mathcal{F}(t^2 F(t-\mu))=\mathcal{F}((t-\mu)^2 F(t-\mu))$?

Comment: Is your goal to evaluate integrals of the form in your post? If so, Fourier transform isn't really helpful. Instead many such integrals may be evaluated by differentiating under the integral and expressing trig functions in complex exponential form.

Comment: For comparison, the discrete version of convolution for $(\Bbb N,+)$ instead of $(\Bbb R,+)$ is polynomial multiplication. If we interpret functions $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ as coefficients of a polynomial, then the convolution $(f\ast g)(k)$ describes the coefficients of the the polynomial product, i.e. $$ \big (\sum f(k)x^k\big) \big( \sum g(\ell)x^\ell\big) = \sum (f\ast g)(n)x^n $$ so that $(f\ast g)(n)=f(0)g(n)+\cdots+f(n)g(0)$. This is intuitive for probability generating functions, for example (where the coefficients are probabilities).

Comment: So the convolution $(f\ast g)(x)$ is different from the composition $(f\circ g)(x):=f(g(x))$ and the product $(f\cdot g)(x):=f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers! Runway44: it may seem small, but the 1-line statement about composition, convolution and product is pretty much what I didn't "get".

Comment: Sal, I figured that I could add the Fourier (or any) transform to my bag of tricks. If the solution I have written above is correct, it's a pretty quick and convenient way to solve it (and more complicated ones). Toward the future, with increased understanding, I think I could get a lot more value out of the transforms - but I first have to understand them before I can do that. I am working on a physics problem, which is easily solved for single x but I'm working towards deducing the distribution of x given a certain measured result z = f(x,y) (where y is varied in the experiment and known).

Comment: @W_vH The Fourier integral $\tilde{F}(\omega)=\int dt \ e^{i\omega t}F(t) $ is no easier to evaluate than your original integral $\tilde{F}(0)$. If you want only $\int dt \ F(t)$, there is no gain in using Fourier analysis. It is true that you can use convolution and other Fourier transform properties to relate the required integral to known transforms from a table, but if you're happy looking up Fourier transforms, why not just look up the original integral? Gradshtein and Rhyzhik is online [here](https://archive.org/details/GradshteinI.S.RyzhikI.M.TablesOfIntegralsSeriesAndProducts/)

Comment: I don't know if you are still interested in this but you are essentially correct. Answer to last two specific questions though are, no, no.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Your answers are helpful in building my confidence, and I greatly appreciate your help. 
It never occurred to me there might be a book where I can look up solutions (and I feel a bit silly about that right now ). That will come in handy at some point.  I’m glad I’m still learning every day. 
I’ll keep “shaking the tree” at my Physics problem, I’m sure something useful will fall out at some point.